# Bug involving vote count.

Tags: bug

When I try to view the vote count, MSE gives an error message "Error in vote count fetch"
Is there any solution? It doesn't happen all the time, but it does happen quite frequently, around 80% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the logs; for *you specifically*, on math.se, over the last 7 days, for that route - we have:

```
response | count
---------+--------
200      |  9
404      |  30
409      |  7
```

which I agree is unusually biased. Checking further, all the broken ones are requests to a broken url; I am investigating where this is coming from, but can I ask what browser you are using, in case that is a factor?

Comment: I'm using, IE 10

Comment: @IshanBanerjee interestingly, network-wide, this has happened 37 times in the last week; all 37 were on math.se, and all 37 were from your account :) I wonder if this is related to some plugin / script that you might be using - do you have anything non-default happening in IE? To be explicit: we suspect a script is being loaded by your browser (for example due to a plugin installed at "your end") - which is breaking this.

Comment: Please could you report what happens if you do the following: press F12; click on the "Console" tab (3rd in); click next to the `>>` so you can type; enter: `String.prototype.format` and press return; you should get a string back starting with `function` - can you copy and paste that line back here please?

Comment: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
 
ancbanner_general_160x600_265.htm, line 1 character 1
Refresh the page to see messages that may have occurred before the F12 tools were opened. 
>> String.prototype.format 
function(){for(var a=this,c=0;c<arguments.length;c++)a=a.replace(RegExp("\\{"+c+"\\}","gi"),arguments[c]);return a} 
Add to watch
>> String.prototype.format 
function(){for(var a=this,c=0;c<arguments.length;c++)a=a.replace(RegExp("\\{"+c+"\\}","gi"),arguments[c]);return a} 
Add to watch

Comment: @IshanBanerjee yep, that has been added by some plugin running in your browser. It is hard to say *what* from here... but if you have a user-script / plugin doing nasty things, it is impossible for us to defend against every possible permutation of that. Are you able to list which plugins / scripts you might be running? Or even better: try disabling them sequentially until it works?

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try and look at all the plugins I have.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee to make it more explicit: *we* use a `String.format` - but the plugin has stomped all over that and replaced it with its own `String.format` *which works differently* - hence any of our code that uses `String.format` is likely to misbehave.